# How to prevent next js from going to fallback routes from static route paths

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using the latest next js. I have a fall back route `app/[...slug]/page.tsx`. I also have `app/contact-us/page.tsx`. But this is behaving weirdly for some of my colleagues. It works fine for me. But for some, clicking any link to `/contact-us`, would give 404 error.

I looked into the issue and it looks like it goes to the fallback route and that is where it throws the 404 error. The `getStaticParams` also do not return the ['about-us'] slug. Not sure why it is happening. I did try filtering the slug. But that did not work for them.

Has anyone faced this issue? And has anyone able to solve this? I am lost. I though that the page should not be rendered if the `getStaticParams` does not return the slug. But it is still passing through the page and throwing `notFound()` for the slug.

Also, it works if I refresh to /contact-us page directly. It is just on client side navigation the page returns 404.

Comment: Ok, it is happening to me as well on the deployed vercel instance. For the context, we are using headless cms. And the data for this deployed instance and our local setup are same. And the `/contact-us` is not included in the slug for `getStaticParams`

Answer (score 1):

I may have not understood your question/file structure exactly but will you try the following?

- This looks good: `/app/[...slug]/page.tsx`
- But this "I also have /app/contact-us.tsx" should be `/app/contact-us/page.tsx`
- ^ in other words, move what you had in `/app/contact-us.tsx` to a new folder + file to match `/app/contact-us/page.tsx`; this change will render the URL the same way you expect ie. `https://www.example.com/contact-us`

(Above is assuming you are using NextJS 13.4+).

Comment: Sorry, I will update the question, it was indeed /app/contact-us/page.tsx

Comment: Are you able to do something like `/app/blog/[...slug]/page.tsx?` to avoid the route conflict?

Comment: Not really, I have to match the slug based on the cms. But, I think I fixed the problem. I think my assumption was wrong, that if the page do not match the slug, it'd not be executed. I just added case for when there is no slug and then handled when we get no data. It seemed to work.